# DEP0040 - DeprecationWarning

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, backend

> [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

I tried downgrading and upgrading the node version but error is not going

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Fruits" );

const fruitScheama = new mongoose.Schema({
  name : String,
  rating : Number
});
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit",fruitScheama);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name : "apple",
  rating : 7
});
fruit.save();
```

Comment: Looks like a known issue that they're attempting to fix. [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/9005).